# Why will the fill color I have selected in Gimp not appear?

Tags: gimp

I am attempting to add a semitransparent layer of color to a black and white image in Gimp 2.8.0. I have added a new layer, clicked the bucket fill tool, selected the foreground color i want to add and adjusted opacity level. But, when I click in the B&W image to fill it, instead of the foreground color I selected (red) I get gray. Am I missing a step or am not using the correct process?

Answer (score 8):

Likely because your image is in grayscale mode (see the window title bar). To use colors freely it has to be in RGB mode (`Image>Mode>RGB`)

Comment: thank you so much for that. somehow the program toggles greyscale mode on at random when i open images in it, and i never knew that was the problem till i looked at the window header